# Python 3, Pandas - delete columns, without deleting headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that originally looked like this:

```
A, B, C, D, ExtraInfo
something, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
something, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
something, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
something, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

I used pandas to modify the headers ExtraInfo column.
Now all my csv files look like this:

```
A, B, C, D, ExtraInfo
something, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
something, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
something, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
something, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
```

**How do I get rid of this extra [comma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKl6umkwKfU)?**

Also, for future reference, how do I modify the header without touching the rest of the info.... This was my first time using pandas so tried several things and have a feeling that I should of just stuck to "rename".

```
def modify_header_board(your_csv):
    df = pd.read_csv(your_csv)
    old_board = (df.columns[-1])
    new_board = (sort_board(old_board))
    df.columns.values[-1] = new_board   <<<< I know this is redundant
    df.rename(columns={old_board:new_board}, inplace=True)
    df.to_csv(your_csv, index=False)
```

Comment: to_csv has a line_terminator option which is just a newline ('\n') by default. It looks like you have 5 columns, but only 4 columns worth of data. Since the last column consists of nulls, it just appears as a trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

for dropping a column in dataframe use

```
df.drop(colname, axis=1)
```

for renaming a header without touching other elements of dataframe use

```
df.columns = ['ColName1', 'ColName2']
```

Comment: df.drop(colname, axis=1) so this will leave my header intact?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using CSV:

```
def csv_to_list(your_csv):
    temp_list = []
    with open(your_csv) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            temp_list.append(row)
    return temp_list

def list_to_csv(your_list):
    with open(file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for item in your_list:
            spamwriter.writerow(item)

def remove_blanks_from_list(your_list):
    new_list = []
    for item in your_list:
        a = []
        for i in item:
            if i != '':
                a.append(i)
        new_list.append(a)
        return new_list


z = csv_to_list(file)
z = remove_blanks_from_list(z)
list_to_csv(z)
```